# ¿Consola de Chrome?

Tags: consola, google-chrome

He investigado un poco y me he encontrado con que existe una consola en google chrome gracias a un pequeño truco en un juego en internet que consta de lo siguiente `MC.showLevelUp(1,10,100)` lo cual creo que es una función.

1. Cómo puedo ver mas funciones (de ser posibles todas) que estén
   disponibles?
2. Y Para qué sirve la consola? Que otras funcionalidades
   tiene?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

En el [sitio oficial](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/console/) de Google Chrome habla sobre la consola.

Para acceder a la consola podes presionar Ctrl + SHift + i[image: Consola de Google Chrome]

Respondiendo tus dos preguntas:

1. La [API](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/console/console-reference) de la consola.
2. La consola sirve para varios propósitos. Una es de la depuración de código. Podes ver warnings, errores, etc. Otra es para hacer pruebas simples usando el motor JavaScript, en vez de crear un archivo html, js, etc. Otra es usar las funcionalidades de JavaScript. Por ejemplo calculadora, etc.

Si sos desarrollador web, la consola de Google Chrome es fundamental para hacer un buen trabajo porque te ahorra mucho tiempo de encontrar errores.